# Repeating code in switch statements

Tags: php, c++

I've got and switch statements like this:

```
switch(x){
    case a:
         executeSth();
         executeA();
    break;
    case b:
         executeSth();
         executeB();
    break;
    ...
}
```

so executeSth(); should allways be executed except in default case but after it some case specific code is called (executeA(); or executeB() and so on). (So simply putting it in front of the switch doesn't work).

Is there an efficient way to reduce the number of "executeSth();" without sacrificing performance?

I could only imagine split it into two switches (one that executes the executeSth() in  and one that executes the specific code) but that would sacrifice performance. Maybe you got better ideas?

I'm basicly interessed in code for c/c++ or php. My goal is to minimize code size and in case of c/c++ the size of the resulting executable.

Edit: Yes, the order of the functions matters.
Edit2: I don't have the choice between php or c++, I need it both to be as good as possible.

Comment: Unless `executeSth()` is a very trivial, inlined function, using two `switch` will not affect performance.  (I might affect readability, however.)

Comment: If you have a choice of C++ or PHP, why are you bothered by trivial performance issues?

Comment: Having two switches (instead of one) will not affect performance unless you're in specific cases (e.g. second switch causing a cache miss). I think you should be fine with two switches (but measure that if performance matters enough to change the code).

Comment: got some problems with performance?

Comment: @Christoph does the order of the function calls matter?

Comment: Is [this what you meant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eea70606ec716895) by redcuing the number of calls?

Comment: @SAM That would run `executeSth()` AFTER `executeA()` etc, which may impact on output.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: [Optimization comes at a price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28computer_science%29#Time_taken_for_optimization)

Comment: @Borgleader: I think in your code executeSth(); would be called even if x != 1 || x != 2 wouldn't it ?

Comment: @All WOW "that escalated quickly" thanks for all the answers and ideas!

Comment: @SweetieBelle Ohh sorry I thought its the reverse way... deleting my comment...

Comment: @Christoph Yes, my question was by number of calls did you mean the number of times the function is called or the number of places `executeSth();` is found

Comment: @Christoph Have added a little test bed for people to test their functions on.

Comment: @Sweetie Belle Did you add it or should I add it ?

Comment: @Christoph I added my two suggestions, just to show that they produce sane output.

Comment: @Christoph Have added a C++ equivelant to my second function using function pointers.

Comment: @Sweeite Belle thank you for all your work ;) I'll wait for a day or two if someone has better ideas if not I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A nested `switch` is an option...

This uses two switches, but the second is not triggered in the `default` case so has a *slightly* better performance profile than just two in-line switches.

```
switch($x) {
    case a: case b: case c:
        executeSth();
        switch($x) {
            case a:
                executeA();
                break;
            case b:
                executeB();
                break;
            case c:
                executeC();
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

### Alternatively, a variable function may do the job...

This is a PHP option which may work, though a lot of people don't like variable functions. This is probably the best option if you want to totally remove nesting & repetition.

```
switch($x) {
    case a:
        $function = "executeA";
        break;
    case b:
        $function = "executeB";
        break;
    case c:
        $function = "executeC";
        break;
    default:
        ...
}

if(isset($function)) {
    executeSth();
    $function();
}
```

I've also made a little [live test bed here](https://eval.in/46491), if anyone wants to test their PHP solutions work before posting them (`case 10` should `executeSth()` and `executeA()`, `case 20` should `executeSth()` and `executeB()`, `default` should `executeDefault()`).

### In C++, you can use a function pointer to achieve the same as the above

I had a total brain fart when I wrote this, thankfully idipous reminded me that we can do this with a simple function pointer.

```
// Declare function pointer
int (*functionCall)() = NULL;

// In switch statement, assign something to it
functionCall = &execute;

// After the switch statement, call it
int result = (*functionCall)();
```

Note: I'm out so haven't checked the syntax on these. The syntax I've used is C syntax and may require some small changes to work in C++.

Comment: God sent answer :) Anything to reduce code repetition! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you could do (although it might not be the most readable solution) and that if you are using PHP 5.3 and above you could create a method like below:

```
function mymethod($funcToCall){
   executeSth();
   $funcToCall();
 }
```

and have the swtich like below:

```
switch(x){
case a:
     mymethod('executeA');
break;
case b:
     mymethod('executeB');
break;
...
}
```

Comment: This is similar to my second solution, it's pretty but I'm not sure if it's portable to C++ in any readable manner.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it before I saw your suggestion. For C++ you would utilize function pointers... but whenever I see these two words together...

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I didn't think about that, I used to use function pointers in C. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is really a huge amount of this sort of thing, I'd leave it as is.

One solution is of course to move the call of `executeSth` into the `executeA` defintion and `executeB` definitions - this is of course only meaningful if there are multiple places with similar code - if there aren't more than one place, you have moved two lines of code from one place to another place.

Another solution may be to pass the function `executeA` or `executeB` into `executeSth` as an argument. But it will just make things more complicated to read.

In general, I'd say "smaller code" is not necessarily "better code". The key is to make the code as clear as possible (whilst still achieving reasonable performance and code-size, of course).

In C++, I would additionally expect that if `executeSth` is small, that it gets inlined into the case-code. So there is no overhead difference between having one or two function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set a flag in your default case, and then, after the switch statement, execute the common function if the flag is not set (meaning that it's not the default case)? That sounds like a reasonable solution.

```
$flag = false;
switch(x){
    case a:
         executeA();
    break;
    case b:
         executeB();
    break;
    default:
         ... // other stuff
         $flag = true;
    break;
}

if ( !$flag )
    executeSth();
```

EDIT

I misinterpreted the question.
For the reverse order you can put the possible cases in a variable and then use something like in_array in PHP or strstr in C++ (not sure if there's a better native function):

```
if ( !in_array(x, cases) {
    executeSth();
}
switch(x){
    case a:
         executeA();
    break;
    case b:
         executeB();
    break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It destroys the order of the 2 calls.

Comment: This would first executeA(); or executeB(); and then it would executeSth();

Comment: I figured out that's what you wanted because you didn't put the common function in front of the switch code and execute it if x doesn't match any of the cases, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

In code size speaking: it doesn't matter. Readability > codesize.

Perhaps you can write something like that for your executeSth():

```
if(!notDefault){
  executeSth();
}
```

Comment: Calculating notDefault would be the same amount as doing 2 switches wouldn't it? Sadly I can't influence the case labels which would allow for a simple x < y; or so. Maybe in some rare cases I can use this.

Comment: This is not a valuable answer, it doesn't do what's asked for.

Comment: @Christoph if you can't restrict it, just do it as you already doing it. That should be fine AND readable.

Answer (score -1):

(C++) Let the preprocessor duplicate the code for you? (**Dᴏɴ’ᴛ Uꜱᴇ Tʜɪꜱ ɪɴ Mᴀɪɴᴛᴀɪɴᴇᴅ Cᴏᴅᴇʙᴀꜱᴇ**. It may hurt readability. I think the two-switch solution is fine.)

```
#define CASE(n) case n: printf("non-default\n"); _unused_label_##n

switch (x) {
CASE(1):
    printf("case 1\n");
    break;
CASE(2):
    printf("case 2\n");
    break;
default:
    printf("case else\n");
    break;
}

#undef CASE
```